# Telerik Kendo UI ASP .NET Autocomplete example not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I merely copied the ASP .NET MVC example from here:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/autocomplete/index

My controller and veiew are exactly the same. But I get no autocomplete suggestions. The debug console throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
AutoCompleteTest:53(anonymous function) 
AutoCompleteTest:53fire jquery-1.10.2.js:3062
self.fireWith jquery-1.10.2.js:3174
jQuery.extend.ready jquery-1.10.2.js:447
completed
```

This is the line of code that is causing it:

`jQuery(function(){jQuery("#countries").kendoAutoComplete({"dataSource":["Albania","Andorra","Armenia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Belarus","Belgium","Bosnia \u0026 Herzegovina","Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Georgia","Germany","Greece","Hungary","Iceland","Ireland","Italy","Kosovo","Latvia","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macedonia","Malta","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Netherlands","Norway","Poland","Portugal","Romania","Russia","San Marino","Serbia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland","Turkey","Ukraine","United Kingdom","Vatican City"],"filter":"startswith","placeholder":"Select country...","separator":", "});});`

EDIT: The _head tag of _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

I have googled but am unable to fix the error. I am using jquery 1.10.x
It's a simple example. I don't know why it's happening or how to fix it :(

Comment: Did you include required scripts? Show us the source?

Comment: It looks like you do not have correctly added kendo script files. Here is the tutorial how to add kendo to mvc3 project: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Added the code for includes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine.The error is due to some compatibility issue with jQuery version.

Make sure you have included all the required scripts for Kendo i.e. "kendo.all.min.js" and others as needed. Also make sure to include the jQuery before including the kendo scripts as kendo is build on top of jQuery.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added the `head` tag where all the scripts are included. I followed the guide from Telerik docs.